# How to make datagridview auto save record when leaving a row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview I want to automatically save each record after editing this record.

Answer (score 5):

There is a `RowValidated` event that would be suitable for this.  You could then pull the values out of the grid and populate your database command.

Answer (score 2):

The following works fine for me:

```
' ListChanged event is called whenever binding or datatable changes
Private Sub ProjectBindingSource_ListChanged(sender As Object, e As
    ListChangedEventArgs) Handles ProjectBindingSource.ListChanged
    Select Case e.ListChangedType
    ' Only update when listchanges are of following types
    Case ListChangedType.ItemChanged, ListChangedType.ItemAdded,
        ListChangedType.ItemDeleted
        Try
            ' Update method will select the required update/insert/delete
            ' SQL according to the tableadapter settings,
            ' after successful update, it will accept changes in
            ' the dataset and change status of all rows back to unchanged.
            Me.ProjectTableAdapter.Update(Me.StuklijstDataSet.Project)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' exceptions will bounce back from the server,
            ' this will handle all possible data problems:
            ' concurrency, foreign key constraints, null not allowed, ... ;
            ' the update method (see above) will also mark the row with
            ' an ErrorProvider icon and tooltip with the error message
            ' if update is unsuccessful, roll back changes to the
            ' datatable.
            Me.StuklijstDataSet.Project.RejectChanges()
            ' resetbindings to sort out problems with the control when rolling back
            ' adding or deleting records
            Me.ProjectBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
        End Try
    End Select
End Sub
```

The event is only raise 3-4 times during loading of the `datatable` and the check of `Listchangedtype` is very fast (< 1 MS).
There is a `RaiseListChangedEvents` property of the `bindingsource` which can be set to False to temporarily turn of the `ListChanged` event, but this seems to cause issues with filling the `datatable`. Turning the event on/off is not required I believe.

The error messages from the server are not very user friendly.
The above method could be extended by reading the exception as a `SqlException` object, retrieving the SQL error code, and changing the `ErrorProvider` message into a more down-to-earth text.

Answer (score 0):

check this 5alid 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/5f8741dc-5874-46e7-8665-6bda3674bafd